# switch statement with off/on boolean

Tags: c++

I've been looking everywhere for this, but haven't found an answer. What I'm trying to achieve is an off/on boolean with a `switch` statement, so multiple options by toggling one key, so if I press, for example, the `up` arrow it toggles the first case. If I press it again it toggles the second case and then the third and so on. It doesn't need to be a `switch` statement, just anything that would work, please point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

This is how an offon boolean is done without `switch` statement, so you get an idea what im searching for.

```
static bool onoff = false;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 1)
{
    onoff = !onoff;
    Sleep(100);
}

if (onoff)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: `bool` states don't need a `switch`, what's your particular problem with that code?

Comment: What's wrong with `if { } else { }`?

Comment: Sound like you want a state machine.

Comment: So in my code theres only two options, off and on, when i press the up arrow it enables the piece of code, when i press it again it disables it, i want to make it so there is multiple options not only two. (but it still gets toggled like an off on switch)

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what you want clearly. As I understand it, you want a button to toggle on/off different things based on the no. of times it is clicked. IMO that's a UI design that can instill murderous intent in your users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer in place of bool.
Suppose you need 5 option to toggle

```
static int i=0;
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & 1)
{
    i++;
    i=i%5;
    Sleep(100);
}
switch (i)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a bunch.